# Angular directive to intercept click event

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-directive, web-frontend, angular13

I want a directive to intercept mouse click event on a whole component.

I wrote an Angular directive to intercept a mouse click event.

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[interceptClick]'
})
export class InterceptClickDirective {
    constructor() {}

    @HostListener('click', ['$event'])
    onClick($event: MouseEvent): void {
      console.log('mouse clicked');
    }
}
```

I want to use it in a component, so I wrote

```
<my-component interceptClick></my-component>
```

but this isn't working.

If I write something like

```
<div>
    <button interceptClick>my button</button>
</div>
```

The directive is working if I click the button.

How do I make the directive work for the whole component?

I'm using Angular 13.

Comment: It works for me on a basic component https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-3wpffp. Maybe the issue is elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

You can either wrap an HTML element around the component or add an HTML element to the component itself, and then add the directive.

```
<div interceptClick>
    <my-component></my-component>
</div>
```

or in the component itself

```
<div interceptClick>
    'All HTML content of the component'
</div>
```